# Uploading and saving a file programmatically to Drupal nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, fileapi

I am trying to create a node based on a custom form submission. Everything works great except for the images that get uploaded.

I can capture them fine and set them in the form object cache. When I pass the data into the function to create the node, I get this error:

"The specified file could not be copied, because no file by that name exists. Please check that you supplied the correct filename."

I also receive the error multiple times, despite only submitting one or two images at a time.

Here is the code I am using. $uploads is passed in and is an array of file objects returned from file_save_upload() in a previous step:

```
if (isset($uploads)) {
    foreach ($uploads as $upload) {
      if (isset($upload)) {
        $file = new stdClass;
        $file->uid = 1;
        $file->uri = $upload->filepath;
        $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($upload->uri);
        $file->status = 1;  

        $file = file_copy($file, 'public://images');

        $node->field_image[$node->language][] = (array) $file;
      }
    }
  }

  node_save($node);
```

I also tried this:

```
if (isset($uploads)) {
    foreach ($uploads as $upload) {
        $upload->status = 1;  

        file_save($upload);

        $node->field_image[$node->language][] = (array) $upload;
      }
    }
  }

  node_save($node);
```

The second causes a duplicate key error in MySQL on the URI field. Both of these examples I saw in tutorials, but neither are working?

Comment: i used `$node->field_image[$node->language][0]`, watch the **0**

Comment: But there are multiple images, so [] is what I'd want not a static value

Comment: right - sorry never used multiple images ..

Comment: maybe an array confusion - try to set the keys explicit ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Drupal 7, I played around with this quite a bit and found the best way (and only way that I've got working) was to use [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers)

I used a managed file form element like so:

```
  // Add file upload widget
  // Use the #managed_file FAPI element to upload a document.
  $form['response_document'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Attach a response document'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('Please use the Choose file button to attach a response document<br><strong>Allowed extensions: pdf doc docx</strong>.'),
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://my_destination/response_documents/',
  );
```

I also pass along the $node object in my form as a value

```
$form['node'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $node);
```

Then in my submission handler I simply do the following:

```
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $node = $values['node'];
  // Load the file and save it as a permanent file, attach it to our $node.
  $file = file_load($values['response_document']);
  if ($file) {
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);

    // Attach the file to the node.
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $wrapper->field_response_files[] = array(
      'fid' => $file->fid,
      'display' => TRUE,
      'description' => $file->filename,
    );
    node_save($node);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

i used your code to upload a file in the file field to a content("document" in my case) and it's worked. Just had to add a value for field_document_file 'display' in the code.
here is the exact script i used:

```
<?php
// Bootstrap Drupal
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
require_once './includes/file.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// Construct the new node object.
$path = 'Documents/document1.doc';
$filetitle = 'test';
$filename = 'document1.doc';

$node = new StdClass();

$file_temp = file_get_contents($path);

//Saves a file to the specified destination and creates a database entry.
$file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

$node->title = $filetitle;
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "The body of test upload document.\n\nAdditional Information";
$node->uid = 1;
$node->status = 1;
$node->type = 'document';
$node->language = 'und';
$node->field_document_files = array(
'und' => array(
    0 => array(
        'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
        'filename' => $file_temp->filename,
        'filemime' => $file_temp->filemime,
        'uid' => 1,
        'uri' => $file_temp->uri,
        'status' => 1,
        'display' => 1
    )
)
);
$node->field_taxonomy = array('und' => array(
0 => array(
    'tid' => 76
)
));
node_save($node);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, that's what I found in the Drupal doc's under http://drupal.org/node/201594 below in the comments. But I am not sure at all. I try the same, so please let me know what you found out.

```
$path = './sites/default/files/test.jpg';
$filetitle = 'test';
$filename = 'test.jpg';

$node = new StdClass();

$file_temp = file_get_contents($path);
$file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

$node->title = $filetitle;
$node->uid = 1;
$node->status = 1;
$node->type = '[content_type]';
$node->language = 'und';
$node->field_images = array(
'und' => array(
    0 => array(
        'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
        'filename' => $file_temp->filename,
        'filemime' => $file_temp->filemime,
        'uid' => 1,
        'uri' => $file_temp->uri,
        'status' => 1
    )
)
);
$node->field_taxonomy = array('und' => array(
0 => array(
    'tid' => 76
)
));
node_save($node);
```